# Coq polymorphic function without explicit type

Tags: coq

I have an "enumerate" function written in the Coq term language (what is it called?). This function is kind of annoying to use because it requires that `A` (the type of an element in the list `l`) be explicitly provided whenever the `enumerate` function is used. Is there a way to avoid needing to explicitly pass `A` as a parameter?

```
(* [a, b] -> [(0,a), (1,b)] *)
Fixpoint enumerate (A : Type) (l : list A) : list (nat * A) :=
  let empty : (list (nat * A)) := nil in
  let incr_pair xy := match xy with 
   | (x, y) => ((S x), y)
  end in 
  match l with
  | nil => empty
  | (x :: xs) => (O, x) :: (map incr_pair (enumerate A xs))
  end.
```

I want to be able to write something like

```
Fixpoint enumerate (l : list A) : list (nat * A) := ...
```

Possibly with some additional syntax identifying what exactly `A` is.

Comment: The Coq term language is called Gallina.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put arguments in brackets to make them implicit by default (see section 2.7.4 [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual004.html)). Also, you should probably write this function in a non-quadratic way with a `nat` accumulator.

```
Require Import Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint enumerate_from {A : Type} (n : nat) (l : list A) : list (nat * A) :=
  match l with
  | [] => []
  | x :: xs => (n, x) :: enumerate_from (S n) xs
  end.

Definition enumerate {A} l : list (nat * A) := enumerate_from 0 l.

Compute (enumerate [3; 4; 5]). (* prints [(0, 3); (1, 4); (2, 5)] *)
```